# Can I set a parameter to accept either an int or a decimal?

Tags: vb.net, types, parameters

Is it possible to accept either a decimal or an integer as a parameter into the same value? For example:

I have an "AddUpdateCondition" subroutine to add parameters to an ODBCCommand and I need to be able to add different data types. Can do i have to just overload the subroutine or can i set the parameter to something such as an object and check if a integer or decimal was passed in?

I would rather one method than these two:

```
Protected Sub AddUpdateCondition(ByVal fieldName As String, ByVal cond As String, ByVal value As String, Optional ByVal type As String = "AND")

    'If a where clause has not been added, create it. 
    If Not sql.ToString.Contains("WHERE") Then
        sql.Append(" WHERE ")
    Else
        sql.Append(" " & type & " ")
    End If

    'Add the condition
    sql.Append(fieldName & " " & cond & " = ?")

    'Add the parameter for this condition
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(fieldName, value)

End Sub

Protected Sub AddUpdateCondition(ByVal fieldName As String, ByVal cond As String, ByVal value As Decimal, Optional ByVal type As String = "AND")

    'If a where clause has not been added, create it. 
    If Not sql.ToString.Contains("WHERE") Then
        sql.Append(" WHERE ")
    Else
        sql.Append(" " & type & " ")
    End If

    'Add the condition
    sql.Append(fieldName & " " & cond & " = ?")

    'Add the parameter for this condition
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(fieldName, value)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it would be easier to use a Generic method.  Notice the type for the value parameter is specified as `As T` and that the method has been made generic by adding `(Of T)` to the method signature.

```
Protected Sub AddUpdateCondition(Of T)(ByVal fieldName As String, ByVal cond As String, ByVal value As T, Optional ByVal type As String = "AND")
    ' If a where clause has not been added, create it. 
    If Not sql.ToString.Contains("WHERE") Then
        sql.Append(" WHERE ")
    Else
        sql.Append(" " & conjunction & " ")
    End If

    ' Add the condition
    sql.Append(fieldName & " " & cond & " = ?")

    ' Add the parameter for this condition
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(fieldName, value)
End Sub
```

And call it like this for a Decimal:

```
AddUpdateCondition(Of Decimal)(...)
```

Or like this for a string:

```
AddUpdateCondition(Of String)(...)
```

Comment: Thank you a bunch. This is exactly what i was looking for. It appears when you call it AddUpdateCondition("example", "=", 10) it automatically sets the type without doing (Of type). Just a heads up, makes the code a bit cleaner!

Comment: @TroyLoberger - Yes, you are correct.  If the compiler can infer the type from the argument passed, then you can omit the `(Of Type)` part.

Comment: Is there a way for a function to return the value of the type? I just posted a question about it [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22099054/return-a-value-from-function-of-the-type-of-a-generic-function)

Answer (score 1):

You could add an optional parameter to your method that specifies the type. Here's your modified code:

```
Protected Sub AddUpdateCondition(ByVal fieldName As String, ByVal cond As String, ByVal value As Decimal, ByVal requestedType As Type, Optional ByVal conjunction As String = "AND")
    ' If a where clause has not been added, create it. 
    If Not sql.ToString.Contains("WHERE") Then
        sql.Append(" WHERE ")
    Else
        sql.Append(" " & conjunction & " ")
    End If

    ' Convert the value
    Dim convertedValue = CTypeDynamic(value, requestedType)

    ' Add the condition
    sql.Append(fieldName & " " & cond & " = ?")

    ' Add the parameter for this condition
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(fieldName, convertedValue)
End Sub
```

Call this method as follows (for an `Integer` value):

```
AddUpdateCondition("name", "cond", 10, GetType(Integer))
```

Comment: When it adds the parameter to do the DB2 update, will there be confusion of updating a field of type Integer with a Decimal type field?

Comment: Thank you very much. It's good to have that knowledge now. However, I'm going to use the format of which Chris supplied. If you havent seen it, its kind of cool. Once again, thanks!